# Why is my function using all iterated items in list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to build a simple program to help me with a fantasy football draft. I've set up a "mock" to predict picks based on a few things, but I'm having an issue storing the right players to the right teams.

EDIT: The problem seems to be that it is storing the pick to every team instead of just the one that I am iterating. I have cleared out all the old code to keep only the new MCVE. Also, I know some of these print statements are redundant / unnecessary. Just using it to spot issues.

```
# This is designed as league set up
class Teams(object):
    def __init__(self, name, draft_position, me):
        self.name = name
        self.draft_position = draft_position
        self.me = me
    roster = {"QB" : "empty", "RB1" : "empty", "RB2" : "empty", "WR1" : "empty ", "WR2" : "empty", "WR3" : "empty", "TE" : "empty", "Flex" : "empty", "K" : "empty", "DEF" : "empty"}
    bench = {}
Team1 = Teams("Team1", 1, False)
Team2 = Teams("Team2", 2, False)
Team3 = Teams("Team3", 3, False)

draft_order = [Team1, Team2, Team3]

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, fantasypros, adp, yahoo_rank, myrank, position):
        self.name = name
        self.fantasypros = fantasypros
        self.adp = adp
        self.yahoo_rank = yahoo_rank
        self.myrank = myrank
        self.position = position
    def mock_pick(self):
        return (self.fantasypros + self.adp + self.yahoo_rank)/3.0


player_data = [("Leveon Bell", 1, 1, 5, 1, "RB"), 
               ("Adrian Peterson", 2, 2, 1, 16, "RB"), 
               ("Jamaal Charles", 3, 3, 3, 7, "RB")] 
player_list = [Player(*player) for player in player_data]
mock_list = [Player(*player) for player in player_data]

def store_pick(z, y):
    print z in mock_list
    if z.position == "RB":
        if y.roster["RB1"] == "empty":
            print y.name
            y.roster["RB1"] = z.name
        elif y.roster["RB2"] == "empty":
            y.roster["RB2"] = z.name
    elif z.position == "WR":
        if y.roster["WR1"] == "empty":
            y.roster["WR1"] = z.name
        elif y.roster["WR2"] == "empty":
            y.roster["WR2"] = z.name
        elif y.roster["WR3"] == "empty":
            y.roster["WR3"] = z.name
    elif z.position == "TE":
        if y.roster["TE"] == "empty":
            y.roster["TE"] = z.name
def remove_pick(z):
    print z in mock_list
    mock_list.remove(z)

def grind(l):
    mock_results = []
    grind_count = 0
    while grind_count < len(mock_list):
        for i in l:
            mock_results.append(i.mock_pick())
            grind_count += 1
    return mock_results
def mock_analyzer(l):
    return min(l)
def pick(b):
    if not t.me:
        for p in mock_list:
            if p.mock_pick() == mock_analyzer(grind(mock_list)):
                if grind(mock_list).count(p.mock_pick()) == 1: #this should figure out if there is a tie
                    if p.position == "RB":
                        if t.roster["RB1"] == "empty":
                            return p
                        elif t.roster["RB2"] == "empty":
                            return p
     else:
         return raw_input("your turn")

# initial draft round code
def mockround(a):
    pick_count = 0
    if a % 2 != 0:
        round_order = draft_order
    else:
        round_order = draft_order.reversed()
    for t in round_order:
        print t.name,
        print "are projected to select"
        d = pick(t)
        print d.name
        remove_pick(d)
        store_pick(d, t)
        pick_count += 1
        print t.name,
        print t.roster
        print Team2.name,
        print Team2.roster
        print Team3.name,
        print Team3.roster




mockround(1)
```

Comment: First, fix your indentation. Second, don't define `store_pick` in the loop; rather, have it take `t` as an argument

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to do. It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Kevin I just added a MCVE. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Really, don't define functions in the loop. The only apparent need to do that is so that the body has access to the loop index, but you can accomplish that by passing the index as an argument. As is, your code is creating new function objects every time the `def` statement is encountered, unnecessarily slowing down your code. Consider this: a function that is defined, then used exactly once immediately afterwards, is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks, @chepner. I will work on this now to get the functions out of the loop. apologies since these are dumb mistakes. this is my first project after an intro course.

Comment: `round_order = draft_order.reverse()` doesn't look right to me. `reverse()` doesn't return anything, so `round_order` would be `None` after that assignment. Did you mean to use `reversed`?

Comment: @Kevin yes, I did. I fixed that and took all the functions out of the loop. Will edit the MCVE, since I'm still having the same problem of it storing the player on every team's roster.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can gather as the question and code is slightly unclear:

Your indentation seems to be wrong and you are declaring functions in a loop which is unnecessary

Here is what I should probably be:

```
for t in round_order: # t is a class instance / object that is a team with a roster. round_order is a list of the instances in the draft order.
    def pick(b): # I won't go into this here, but this is designed to return the projected pick (which is a class instance / object that is a player, with position info) and it seems to be working.
    d = pick(t)
    print d.name
    remove_pick(d)
    store_pick(d)

def store_pick(z): # this isn't fully fleshed out, but there's enough to get the idea.
                if z.position == "RB":
                    if t.roster["RB1"] == "empty":
                        t.roster["RB1"] = z.name
                    elif t.roster["RB2"] == "empty":
                        t.roster["RB2"] = z.name
                elif pick(t).position == "WR":
                    if t.roster["WR1"] == "empty":
                        t.roster["WR1"] = z.name
                    elif t.roster["WR2"] == "empty":
                        t.roster["WR2"] = z.name
                    elif t.roster["WR3"] == "empty":
                        t.roster["WR3"] = z.name
                elif pick(t).position == "TE":
                    if t.roster["TE"] == "empty":
                        t.roster["TE"] = z.name
def remove_pick(z):
        mock_list.remove(z) # mock_list is a list of instances / objects in the player class. I want to remove it so that player is not available for the next pick.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried adding a MCVE to make it clearer what I am trying to do. I also incorporated your suggestions into that example.

Comment: This needs some work. `store_pick` and `remove_pick` need to be defined *before* they are used in the loop, and the `t` in `store_pick` is no longer linked to the loop-index `t`.

Comment: @chepner, could you tell me how to link the argument `y` in `store_pick` to loop-index `t`? I think that is the root of my problem

Comment: You pass it as an argument, the same way you do with `z`.

Comment: @chepner do you mind taking a look at my updated OP? That's what I tried to do, but without success. Thanks!